# Sharepoint 2013 linking of lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

How can I link two lists on different sites of sharepoint 2013, I do not want to have the view of one to the other site. I want to connect one column to the column of another list on different site that if I enter data in one list it will automatically add on the other list of other site.

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint Designer workflow, we can only do actions such as create items in the same site for the SharePoint 2013.

To create items or do other actions in the list in another site automatically, you need code. An idea is that using the Event Receiver to handle the list events. When an item is added to the list, operate another list in the another site per your requirement.

[How to create an Event Receiver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If you are using the SharePoint Online, use a [Remote Event Receiver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-a-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins).